# HoloLens 2 Emulator Error 0x80004003 - Object reference not set to an instance of an object

Tags: hololens, windows-mixed-reality, hololens-emulator

I have been trying to deploy a Unity application to the Hololens 2 emulator for a while now and have not found a solution that works.

I have run through every troubleshooting document and uninstalled and reinstalled every program to try and find the right fit but keep getting the same error. I have gotten the application to deploy to the Hololens device itself, but the emulator refuses to open. I can install the emulator with no errors and have the updated SDK and have verified all the project settings with the development page. Any suggestions on what to do next?

Comment: Did you mean that you are available to deploy the solution to the HoloLens 2 device successfully?Could the Hololens 2 Emulator be start successfully?

Comment: Which version of emulator do you use? Do you able to start emulator itself without an app? How do you install an app?

Comment: I have gotten the app to deploy to the hololens 1 device. 
I am using the most up-to-date versions of Visual Studio 2017, Windows SDK, the Hololens 2 Emulator, and Unity 2018.4

Answer (score 1):

Can you please share the output of running the following two commands in an Administrator PowerShell window?  I suspect you're hitting an installation issue that's placing the emulator into the wrong folder.

```
(Get-Item -path "${env:ProgramFiles(x86)}\Windows Kits\10\Microsoft XDE\10.0.18362.0\XDE.exe").VersionInfo.ProductVersion

Get-ItemProperty -Path "HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows Kits\Installed Roots\" -Name "KitsRoot10"
```